# codeigniter use part of query result in another query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

It was hard to come up with a title. I am using CodeIgniter with models/views/controller. I have the following tables in my MySQL database that are relevant:

[image]

In my model I have the following function:

```
function get_shoptable() {
    $this->db->from('productshop')->where('productId', $this->productId);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

In my controller I use the above function like

```
$data['bookshop'] = $this->Product_model->get_shoptable();
```

In my view I am foreaching $bookshop. My problem is, what is the best wayto show shopName, instead of showing shopId. Taking in regards that $bookshop should be as it is (except of shopid), because I am creating a HTML table with product data.

Comment: just don't use the shopId from the result set.either use select statement to choose specific columns

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Your answer does not really help me, maybe I should specificy my question. Can I make a query which gets all the data from productshop (with the restriction of the productId) and gets the needed shopName from shop?

Comment: @Orhan, Check my answer, If you want I can extend it more all the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try some like this:

```
function get_shoptable() {
    $this->db->from('productshop')
    ->join('shop', 'productshop.shopId = shop.shopId')
    ->where('productshop.productId', $this->productId);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: Very cool, thanks, that worked! But how can that work if you do not select shopName? In the profiler I see the query build like: 


    SELECT *
FROM (`productshop`)
JOIN `shop` ON `productshop`.`shopId` = `shop`.`shopId`
WHERE `productshop`.`productId` =  116774

Answer (score 1):

Model:

```
function get_products() {
    $this->db->select('productshop.productUrl, productshop.price, productshop.deliveryTime, productshop.shippingCast, productshop.inventory, productshop.productId, productshop.shopId, shop.shopName');
    $this->db->from('productshop');
    $this->db->join('shop', 'productshop.shopId = shop.shopId');
    $this->db->where('productshop.productId', $this->productId);
    return $this->db->get()->result_array();
}
```

Controller:

```
function products() {
    $data['products'] = $this->model_name->get_product();
    $this->load->view('products', $data);

}
```

VIEW:

```
<?php foreach($products as $p): ?>
<h1><?php echo $p['productUrl']; ?></h1>
<h1><?php echo $p['shopName']; ?></h1>
<?php endforeach(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

get an overlook to [active class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) of codeigniter for details of functions

```
function get_shoptable()
 {
    $this->db->from('productshop')
    $this->db->join('shop', 'productshop.shopId = shop.shopId')
    $this->db->where('productshop.productId', $this->productId);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```